# execute rule if only the target is defined in node js

Tags: regex, angularjs, node.js, if-statement

I am replacing color, font and font size in the server according to the users choice in the client side. In my program user can proceed without choosing all 3 of them (the user can choose only color and font etc.), so those variable values will be undefined. My code below is only to changes all 3 variables and if its undefined, it replaces it as undefined.

```
    var userId = req.userId;
    var appId = req.body.appId;
    var main = 'temp/' + userId + '/templates/' + appId + '/css/main.css';

    var color = req.body.color;
    var font = req.body.font;
    var fontSize = req.body.fontSize;

    function updateFile(filename, replacements) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
            fs.readFile(filename, 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
                var regex, replaceStr;
                if (err) {
                    throw (err);
                } else {
                    for (var i = 0; i < replacements.length; i++) {
                        regex = new RegExp("(\\" + replacements[i].rule + "\\s*{[^}]*" + replacements[i].target + "\\s*:\\s*)([^\\n;}]+)([\\s*;}])");
                        replaceStr = "$1" + replacements[i].replacer + "$3";
                        data = data.replace(regex, replaceStr);
             if(replacements[i].target == undefined){
                    replacements[i].rule = !replacements[i].rule;
                }//if condition which I have tried
                  }

                  fs.writeFile(filename, data, 'utf-8', function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            throw (err);
                        } else {
                            resolve();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }

    updateFile(main, [

        {rule: ".made-easy-themeColor", target: "color", replacer: color},
        {rule: ".made-easy-themeFont", target: "font-family", replacer: font},
        {rule: ".made-easy-themeFontSize", target: "font-size", replacer: fontSize + "em"}
    ], function (err) {
        console.log((err));
    });
```

My aim is only to execut `rule` if `target` according to that is defined.
I have tried putting,

```
 if(replacements[i].target == undefined){
    replacements[i].rule = !replacements[i].rule;
   }
```

as I have mentioned above in the code but it is not working. Please can anyone tell me how to put the conditions in the above code

Comment: What is the behavior now, can you elaborate "not working"?

Comment: Print the replacements in console by 
console.log(replacements[i]);
before if statement and let me tell output

Comment: it replaces all three variables in main and if the user don't choose anything, for an example if user select only color and font the fonrSize value is undefined and when the above function execute it replaces the fontSize value as undefind(write in file main as                                 .made-easy-themeColor     {
 color: hsl(0, 33%, 35%)
  }
  .made-easy-themeFont {
   font-family: Arial;
  }
  .made-easy-themeFontSize {
   font-size: undefinedem;
  } )I want if font-size is not defined then its value should not change

Comment: check condition like if ( req,body.color==undefined) if it is true then set default color to variable. you have to do for other 2 variable

Comment: @Arvaan output in console is { rule: '.made-easy-themeColor',
  target: 'color',
  replacer: 'hsl(0, 36%, 31%)' }
{ rule: '.made-easy-themeFont',
  target: 'font-family',
  replacer: 'Ubuntu Light' }
{ rule: '.made-easy-themeFontSize',
  target: 'font-size',
  replacer: '26em' }

Comment: `target`is defined, so it behaves as it should according to the rule. Should you be checking `target`?

Comment: I tried using if condition with target as above but it is not working